# Can I install SQL Server 2012 standard edition on a machine with 2012 developer version

Tags: sql-server

I've installed Windows 2012 Standard OS and SQL Server 2012 Developer edition.
And I want to install a 2nd instance of SQL Server 2012 Standard edition.

Can both instances be run without any issues, or what challenges may occur?

Please help to configure this setup.

Comment: The second instance just needs a *different* instance name - that's all. No problems to be expected - I typically have 3-4 instances in parallel on my dev machine ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can different  Editions of SQL server on same Machine with out any issues as long as you Provide different instance names

Comment: I dont see an issue,i have SQL server 2016 trial version running on same computer